# Why does find and exec mv not move all files?

Tags: find, mv

The current working directory has multiple test files numbered between 1 to 100. These are titled `1.txt` through to `100.txt`.

The command `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[ -._&a-zA-Z0-9]+\.txt' -exec bash -c 'mv "$@" "TestDir - Level One"' {} +` moves all files bar one e.g. `15.txt`.

In contrast the command `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[ -._&a-zA-Z0-9]+\.txt' -exec mv {} "TestDir - Level One"/ \;` moves all files.

If the command `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[ -._&a-zA-Z0-9]+\.txt' -exec bash -c 'mv "$@" "TestDir - Level One"' {} +` is executed again, it returns the error `mv: missing destination file operand after 'TestDir - Level One' Try 'mv --help' for more information.`

The version of `find` is `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the assignment of the `$0` string to the `bash -c '…'` call. The first argument of the `find` call is assigned to `$0` (the name of the shell) instead of `$1` and is thus not moved.

> `-c`     If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string. If there are arguments after the command_string, **the first argument is assigned to `$0` and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters. 
>    The assignment to `$0` sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Change your command to

```
find . [more find options…] -exec bash -c 'mv "$@" "TestDir - Level One"' bash {} +
```

Comment: +1 ... one of the things I can't ever seem to remember completely. However the placeholder you use is confusing (for beginners) I think, because it does look like the reserved word `bash`, doesn't it ?

Comment: @Freddy - Would you mind elaborating on `$0` and `$1` and the role it plays? Secondly, is the command using `bash` more effective and/or efficient to `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[ -._&a-zA-Z0-9]+\.txt' -exec mv {} "TestDir - Level One"/ \;`? If yes, why? The reason I ask is that the recommendation (from my understanding) is that `{} +` caters for scenarios such as spaces, new lines and the like whilst `\;` does not. However the use of `bash` seems to make it more complicated.

Comment: When you execute a bash script like `./myscript.sh foo bar`, then `$0` becomes the path of the invoked script `./myscript.sh` and the positional parameters `$1` and `$2` are `foo` and `bar`. In your bash shell the value of `$0` is something like `-bash` (for a login shell). If you execute bash with `-c` and a command string _and_ positional parameters you have to provide this string. Try `bash -c 'echo "\$0:$0, args:$@"' nameofmyshell one two` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: It would be more efficient to you use `… -exec mv {} "TestDir - Level One" +` (or more readable `… -exec mv -t "TestDir - Level One" {} +`) since you're executing an unnecessary bash process 
with `bash -c`, but it's obvious that you need a script for more complex examples. The difference between `+` and `\;`: 
Both handle filenames with spaces etc. well. The difference is that `\;` executes `mv` once for each argument and `+` moves as many files as possible with one `mv` call (faster, more efficient).

Comment: @Freddy - Thanks for elaborating on the question as well as providing the additional context.

Comment: @Freddy - The suggestion `exec mv {} "TestDir - Level One" +` results in the error `find: missing argument to `-exec'` whereas `-exec mv -t "TestDir - Level One" {} +` works.

Comment: Yes, my bad, didn't test the example. Use `-exec mv -t ... {} +` or `-exec mv {} ... \;`. Sorry, no email contact.